# Move pagination outside a component in Slider React

Tags: reactjs, pagination, swiper.js

I have a problem trying to move a pagination bullet outside the slider, specifically below the slider image.

This is how I define the swiper.

```
<Grid container style={{ marginBottom: 115 }}>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        navigation
        pagination
        breakpoints={{
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 1
          },
          1000: {
            slidesPerView: 2
          },
          1300: {
            slidesPerView: 4
          }
        }}
      >
        <div>
          {sliders.map((news) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={news.codigo}>
              <Sliders info={news} />
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    </Grid>
```

This is the css what I use for style the swiper

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  right: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: rgb(0, 162, 255) !important;
  fill: rgb(0, 163, 255) !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  border: solid rgb(255, 241, 241);
}

:root {
  --swiper-navigation-size: 26px;
}

.swiper-contrainer {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 300ms opacity;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 2;
  top:97%;
}
```

Here's how I got now, the pagination bullets need to got out of the green container

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can assign an element to be the pagination container by adding `el` parameter in `pagination` props and putting the container outside the slider. See the swiper [document](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination-parameters) for detail.

Example:

```
   <Grid container style={{ marginBottom: 115 }}>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        navigation
        pagination: {{
            el: '.swiper-custom-pagination',
          }},
        breakpoints={{
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 1
          },
          1000: {
            slidesPerView: 2
          },
          1300: {
            slidesPerView: 4
          }
        }}
      >
        <div>
          {sliders.map((news) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={news.codigo}>
              <Sliders info={news} />
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Swiper>
      <div className="swiper-custom-pagination"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It gives error: Uncaught TypeError: extendParams is not a function
    at Grid